# How to properly extend the Laravel 5.7 Router?

Tags: php, laravel

This question has been discussed many times [here](https://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2015-l5-extending-router), [here](https://blog.lanin.me/extending-default-laravel-router/) or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/9tpji3/question_extending_laravel_router/) but no elegant solutions were mentioned.

One particular use case would be to allow to load and route old PHP files with Laravel. I am for instance migrating a very old (> 20 years) code base into Laravel and most pages are regular PHP files that I would like to render into a particular Blade template.

To do this it would be elegant to do:

```
Router::php('/some/route/{id}', base_path('legacy/some/page.php'));
```

Behind the scenes all I need is to pass the captured variables to the PHP page, evaluate and grab the content of it and eventually return a view instance.

As Laravel claims itself to be a SOLID framework, I thought extending the Router is trivial so I wrote this:

namespace App\Services;

```
class Router extends \Illuminate\Routing\Router
{
    public function php($uri, $filename, $template='default') {
        ...
        return view(...
    }
}
```

Then I tried to extend my Http Kernel with this:

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

use App\Services\Router;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router) {
        return parent::__construct($app, $router);
    }
}
```

But it is not working it seems the Application is building the Kernel with the wrong dependency. In `Application@registerCoreContainerAliases` I see the core alias `router` is hard coded and since this method is called in the Application's constructor, I am doomed.

The only solution that remains is to override the router before loading the Kernel as follow:

```
$app = new Application($_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__));

$app->singleton('router', \App\Services\Router::class);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);
```

But this looks a bit ugly. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [Router](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html) class is [macroable](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.html), you may be able to do something like:

```
Router::macro('php', function ($uri, $filepath) {
    return $this->addRoute(['GET', 'POST', etc...], $uri, function () use ($filepath) {
        // here you might use the blade compiler to render the raw php along with any variables.
        // 
        // See: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesRawPhp.html
        //

        $contents = file_get_contents($filepath);

        // return compiled $contents...
    });
});
```